# ath leaves many open sockets

Tags: macos, itunes, catalina, data-synchronization, resources

This seems somehow similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153809/usbmuxd-takes-all-sockets-no-other-network-connection-possible). While diagnosing some weird application behaviour on my MacBook Pro and the dreaded "too many open files" errors appearing in the shell out of nowhere, I came to find out that `ath`, an executable component of `AirTrafficHost.framework`, keeps a huge number of open sockets in `CLOSE_WAIT` state. The number tends to only increase in time until it hits the system limit for open file descriptors. I use my MBP docked most of the time and it is always on, so the limit is reached after a couple of days.

`AirTrafficHost.framework` is a private Apple framework and seems to be part of the wireless communcation with iOS devices. There are two iOS devices for which I've enabled network sync - an iPad Pro and an iPhone. It seems that `ath` tries to talk to them and at some point the connection is terminated, but the network sockets are never closed and just keep piling up. `lsof` shows:

```
ath  627 hristo   7u  IPv6 0x2e106590d5ff22b3  0t0  TCP [fe80:5::xxx]:49280->[fe80:5::yyy]:57461 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ath  627 hristo   8u  IPv6 0x2e106590d6aea413  0t0  TCP [fe80:5::xxx]:49300->[fe80:5::yyy]:57464 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ath  627 hristo  10u  IPv6 0x2e106590d7a65c93  0t0  TCP [fe80:5::xxx]:49529->[fe80:5::yyy]:57482 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ath  627 hristo  11u  IPv6 0x2e106590d4fe9a33  0t0  TCP [fe80:5::xxx]:49574->[fe80:5::yyy]:57486 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ath  627 hristo  13u  IPv6 0x2e106590d5feeb93  0t0  TCP [fe80:5::xxx]:49609->[fe80:5::yyy]:57490 (CLOSE_WAIT)
ath  627 hristo  14u  IPv6 0x2e106590d18e7b93  0t0  TCP [fe80:5::xxx]:49656->[fe80:5::yyy]:57494 (CLOSE_WAIT)
... many more ...
```

Right now, it's been 5 hrs since the last reboot and the number of socket descriptors is already 162 in two `ath` processes (one for each iOS device, I guess) and growing:

```
$ lsof -n | grep ^ath | grep TCP | wc -l
    162
```

It also seems that for each disconnect, there is an entry in `/var/log/system.log`:

```
Mar 17 01:15:23 MacBook-Pro AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[433]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:159
Mar 17 01:15:23 MacBook-Pro AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[433]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:159
Mar 17 01:15:23 MacBook-Pro AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[433]: tid:7387 - Mux ID not found in mapping dictionary
Mar 17 01:15:23 MacBook-Pro AMPDeviceDiscoveryAgent[433]: tid:7387 - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid
```

The OS is a fully updated macOS Catalina 10.15.3.

Is anyone else seeing the same problem and are you aware of a solution that does not involve increasing the system limits or performing a clean OS install? I already have a `launchd` job to increase `kern.maxfiles` and `kern.maxfilesperproc`, but that's not really a solution - it just postpones the problem. And I'd prefer not to disable network synchronisation, because I'm out of USB ports.

Comment: My machine has been running for 5 days, and ath now has 5583 open sockets, most of which are stuck in CLOSE_WAIT state. This must be some kind of bug. I'm on Catalina 10.15.4

Answer (score 1):

It is actually okay to raise the system limits - for example up to 65536 open files. 162 sockets over 5 hours is a relatively low number. It is not going to affect system performance in any way, and does not use up any kind of significant resources.

Ordinarily sockets will eventually go away by themselves after a timeout. However in your case, they're listed as being in state CLOSE_WAIT. This means that the kernel is waiting for the application to call close() on the socket descriptor, and they will not go away automatically.

`ath` is supposed to be doing just that - so it seems like you've either hit a bug, or have some kind of serious misconfiguration that makes `ath` behave incorrectly.

As a temporary measure, you can get the sockets closed by closing the `ath` process. You can see the process ID in your output from lsof, and then use the `kill` command to close it up. You can start it again from:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTrafficHost.framework/ath
```

Comment: There is no timeout for sockets in `CLOSE_WAIT` state. The only way to get them out of that state is to close the descriptor, which isn’t happening, most likely due to a software bug, or to kill the process. I’m investigating the ramifications of the latter and will probably end up with a periodic job that calls `killall`.

Comment: Ah, you're right - I didn't look closely at the lsof output due to scrolling. Sounds like an good way of handling the symptom for now, but shouldn't really happen!